# How can I get out a specific value from my data?

Tags: javascript, json

What I would like to do is to declare a variable that has the IsUserSiteOwner value from the data.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: data["GetProcess..."][0]["IsUserSiteOwner"]

Answer (score 1):

JSON is literally just JavaScript so you can access the properties using dot-notation:

```
var b = data["GetProcessDocumentLinksResult"][0].IsUserSiteOwner;
```

Comment: *"JSON is literally just JavaScript"* No, it isn't: http://json.org It's a textual data notation **based on** a very limited subset of JavaScript object initializer syntax. What the OP is dealing with is not text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you've shown in yellow is what you're trying to deal with, that's not JSON, that's an array containing an object. JSON is a *textual* data notation. Something has already deserialized the JSON for you.

To access that, you'd use `[0]` to get to the one entry in the array (the object), then `.IsUserSiteOwner` to get to its property. Since `b` is what you had highlighted:

```
var variable = b[0].IsUserSiteOwner;
```